# Managed code in unmanaged

Tags: .net, delphi

if i'm using .net dll from delphi code, by exporting types, will managed code have his own thread or it will work in delphis thread? or i must create thread in dll, if i want it to work in new thread?

i want to call .net function, from unmanaged code. and i want it to work async.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The managed code will not get any new thread automatically. You need to spin of a thread yourself and call the managed code on that thread.

Of course you can use threads internally in the .NET code.